# JAVA_HOME is not set correctly after adding and appending to PATH

Tags: ubuntu, bash, java

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Bash version 4.3.11(1)-release

I've added $JAVA_HOME to ~/.profile (and .bash_profile) like this:

```
#
# This is the default standard .profile provided to sh users.
# They are expected to edit it to meet their own needs.
#
# The commands in this file are executed when an sh user first
# logs in.
#
# $Revision: 1.10 $
#

# Set the interrupt character to Ctrl-c and do clean backspacing.
if [ -t 0 ]
then
        stty intr '^C' echoe
fi

# Set the TERM environment variable
eval `tset -s -Q`

# Set the default X server.
if [ ${DISPLAY:-setdisplay} = setdisplay ]
then
    if [ ${REMOTEHOST:-islocal} != islocal ]
    then
        DISPLAY=${REMOTEHOST}:0
    else
        DISPLAY=:0
    fi
    export DISPLAY
fi


# List files in columns if standard out is a terminal.
ls()    { if [ -t ]; then /bin/ls -C $*; else /bin/ls $*; fi }

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/bin/java)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

But still typing echo $JAVA_HOME yields:

```
XXX:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME /usr/local/lib/jdk-8u25/
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `JAVA_HOME` is set again later in the initialisation file sequence. Try `grep JAVA_HOME .profile .bash*` to check. However, `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/bin/java)` is wrong: this sets `JAVA_HOME` to the first token in the output from running `/usr/bin/java`, but this generates help text on standard error and nothing on standard output, so `JAVA_HOME` is set to an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/bin/java)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

Using the variable assignment with a `$()` tells Linux to do a command substitution. So, it is trying to run the command `/usr/bin/java` and assign the output to the variable.

You should use:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

Then to make the new variables live, execute your profile script:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Note the extra `.` at the beginning. Without it the variable assignment would only persist within the scope of the script.